# How to create tensor with shape=[0, 4]?

Tags: tensorflow

For 1D, I can create tensor with shape=[0], like `tf.constant([])`
But For 2D, how can I create tensor with shape=[0,4]

I want to concat two tensor, like this:

```
A is tensor # A.shape=[0,4]

A=concat([A,B])  # B.shape=[2,4]

A=concat([A,C])  # C.shape=[3,4]
```

For some reason, I can't get B and C simultaneously, so I need to create a tensor with shape=[0,4].

Answer (score 0):

The [`tf.zeros()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/zeros) op provides an easy way to create a tensor of a specific size. Since the tensor you are creating has no elements, the choice of zeros is arbitrary, and you could likewise use [`tf.ones()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/zeros) or [`tf.fill()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/fill) to create the tensor. The following three options are equivalent:

```
A = tf.zeros([0, 4])

A = tf.ones([0, 4])

A = tf.fill([0, 4], 37.0)
```